# How to pass params[:search] with autocomplete_field_tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, autocomplete

I am using the [Crowdint rails3 jquery autocomplete](https://github.com/crowdint/rails3-jquery-autocomplete) and having trouble with my search form.

This is how my `search` form looks without autocomplete:

```
<%= form_tag search_path, :method => 'get' do %>
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], :placeholder => "Search for a Product.....", :id => "main-search-field" %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil, :id => "main-search-field-button" %>
<%end%>
```

Now when I change around the form for autocomplete and search:

```
<%= form_tag search_path, :method => 'get' do %>
   <%= autocomplete_field_tag 'name','', search_autocomplete_product_name_path, params[:search], :placeholder => "Search for a Product.....", :id => "main-search-field" %>
   <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil, :id => "main-search-field-button" %>
<%end%>
```

This will not work if I have `params[:search]` inside of my `autocomplete_field_tag`:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (wrong number of arguments (5 for 4))
```

**How do I set the search parameter so I can actually search with autocomplete?**

---

More info:

```
class SearchController < ApplicationController
  autocomplete :product, :name, :full => true

  # Sunspot search.
  def index
    @search = Product.search do
      fulltext params[:search]
      paginate(:per_page => 1, :page => params[:page])
    end
    @products = @search.results
  end
end

# routes.rb
get 'search/autocomplete_product_name'
resources :search, :only => [:index]
```

Answer (score 4):

*(Disclaimer: I've no experience with this particular gem, the following answer is based on a brief look through it's source only.)*

The `autocomplete_field_tag` method takes five parameters according to the source, the last one being an options hash:

```
autocomplete_field_tag(name, value, source, options = {})
```

So, given that your controller method e.g. needs a parameter called `product_name` your method call should probably read:

```
autocomplete_field_tag('product_name', '', search_autocomplete_product_name_path, :placeholder => "Search for a Product.....", :id => "main-search-field")
```

Comment: This gets the autocompletion to work, same with my above code but what about passing the :search parameters? It won't let me search if I don't have that their I believe. I will post the code I would normally use for this, to the search to work.

Comment: What does this parameter contain? Where are you setting it?

Comment: In my edit is my controller, view, and routes. I am using Sunspot and as you can see in the block, to do fulltext searching I am passing the `params[:search]` inside of it.

Comment: @LearningRoR Have you solved this issue. I am getting same issue