# What's a good autocomplete to use for a Search field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am looking for an autocomplete ( or autosuggest) that is good for a search field like this:

```
<%= form_tag search_path, :method => :get do %>
  <p>
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
<% end %>
```

I try to use [Crowdint rails3 jquery autocomplete](https://github.com/crowdint/rails3-jquery-autocomplete)  but it does not work because of the `params[:search]` inside of the search `text_field_tag`.

What are my other options for autocomplete?

Comment: Well.. you could try replacing the `params[:search]` with `@search` ?

Comment: OK, I did try this: `<%= autocomplete_field_tag 'name', '', search_autocomplete_product_name_path, @search %>` but it still didn't work. Thanks for the input though. If you have any other ideas I have a question on it:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8106902/how-to-get-a-search-field-to-pass-params-with-crowdint-jquery-autocomplete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theres an autocomplete in the jQuery ui library => http://jqueryui.com/

The autocomplete provided by jQuery UI is just a basic autocomplete like you know from sites like google.

You can also use a library which finds on jQuery like token inputs => http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/ it matters which kind of autocomplete you want. Token Inputs is for selecting specific content which has a name and an id. The autocomplete provided by jQuery ui also needs a datasource but its more flexible and doesn't force you to select one of the existing entries.

Comment: Which library (jquery ui autocomplete or loopj tokeninput) would you suggest as 'default' option = as a starting point for evaluation?

Answer (score 0):

There is a great screencast by Ryan Bates on autocomplete fields.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/102-auto-complete-association-revised